# Exclude domains from Traefik Let's Encrypt

Tags: docker, traefik

I am using [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) as Reverse Proxy in a Docker environment. Every dockerized application is getting it's Traefik configuration as labels, like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=whoami"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:internal.domain.com,external.domain.com;PathPrefixStrip:/whoami"
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - "80"
    restart: always
networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

Applications are accessible via an internal domain (intranet) and an external domain.

Now I am getting `Error creating new order :: too many failed authorizations recently: see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/, url: "` from Let's Encrypt, because Traefik tries to get a certificate for a domain which is not  accessible from external.

Is there any way to exclude domains from Traefik's Let's Encrypt support?

Answer (score 0):

The docker-compose label `traefik.enable=false` should disable it:

```
    labels:
    - traefik.enable=false
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Wouldn't that label disable the domain external.domain.com as well?